# Calculating number of combinations for stacking blocks

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem with blocks that are stacked on top of each other and stacks are positioned next to each other.
The number of stacks `w` (width) and the number of blocks `b` are variables.
The height of a stack is [0,4]. A block can only be positioned on the bottom of a stack or on top of another stack (i.e. we have to respect gravity). All blocks are unique, so vertical and horizontal ordering are important.

Here is a sample of three different layouts for `(w,b) = (4,8)`

```
     6        6            6   
     3        3            3   
 7   8        8   7        8   5 2
 5 4 1 2      1 4 5 2      1   7 4
---------    ---------    ---------
```

I need to calculate the number of possible layouts.

I started by calculating the number of combinations of stack heights. E.g.:

- 4 4 0 0
- 4 3 1 0
- 4 2 2 0
- 4 2 1 1
- ...

However, I did not manage to generalize this. We are talking about permutations with variable repeatable items depending on the sum of items.

Maybe I have the wrong approach and we should only concentrate on distributing `b` blocks in `w` stacks. But how do I remove the invalid combinations that have blocks floating in the air?

Thank you for your help. :)

P.S. If you wish, you can make the height [0,h] a variable as well. Then we would have `(w,h,b)`

Comment: Does the order of the stacks matter?  Is there a set number of stacks?

Comment: The order of stacks matters and the number of stacks is set for one instance of the problem. But I need to calculate this for w,b = 4,8; 4,12; 5,10; 5,15; ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the number of arrangements of block height.  This is the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) that respect your constraints:$b$ items into $w$ parts at most $h$. Without the "at most $h$" part, that is ${b+w-1 \choose w-1}$  This gives you an ordered set of stack heights, which tells you all the block positions.  Now there are $b!$ ways to locate the blocks in those positions, so the total is ${b+w-1 \choose w-1}b!$  With the maximum part of $h$ you can use generating functions:  take the coefficient of $x^b$ in $(1+x+x^2+\dots x^h)^w$ and multiply by $b!$

Comment: Yes. That works!

Comment: Tnx! I cant remember how to use generating functions, and WolframAlpha refuses to cooperate. Could you help me compute this please?

Comment: I know its the seriescoefficient[..., b] function but getting the right seriesdata is giving me trouble.

Comment: SeriesCoefficient[(Sum[x^i, {i,0,h}])^w, {x,0,b}]*(b!)

Comment: Use lemma 2 from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780969/) to get a closed form for "b items into w parts at most h". Then, there is no need of the generating function.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the order of the stacks matter? Is there a set number of stacks?

If there is a set number of stacks $w$ and the order of the stacks matters (and some stacks may be empty), then count the permutations of blocks and $w-1$ borders between stacks.

$b$ distinct objects in $w$ distinct stacks, where ordering in and of the stack matters, can be arranged $\frac{(b+w-1)!}{(w-1)!}$ ways.

If a maxium stack height is set it... complicates things.  I suspect we have to look into [restricted partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partiitions).

Comment: How does this respect height? edit: I see your edit.

Comment: I suspect we have to look into restricted partitions.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partiitions

Comment: you were on a good path, i would vote up your answer but i don't have enough karma