# Number of binary and constant-weight strings of length m which do not contain k consecutive zeros

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bit-strings

I am considering the set of all finite and binary strings. In the following I am interested on the number $N(m,k,r)$ of strings with length $m$ and Hamming weight $r$ which do not contain $k$ consecutive zeros.

The Hamming weight $r$ is defined as the number of non-zero positions in a string.

**Example:** The binary string $x=1001101$ is given. The Hamming weight of $x$ is $r=4$, since $x$ contains 4 non-zero entries.

Is there a general formulary for computing $N(m,k,r)$?

Comment: Hint: Fix some $k$ (e.g. $k = 2$ or $k=3$) and some $r$ and compute your numbers for consecutive $m$. Then, fix e.g. $m$ and let $r$ vary. Put the sequences you find into OEIS and look what turns up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $N(m,k,r)$  denote the  number of  binary strings with length $m$ and Hamming weight $r$ which do not contain zero-runs of length $k$.

> The following is valid for $m\geq 1, k\geq 1, 0\leq  r\leq m$
>   \begin{align*}
> N(m,k,r)&=\sum_{j= 0}^{\min\left\{r,\left\lfloor \frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor\right\}}\binom{m-kj}{j}\binom{m-(k+1)j}{r-j}(-1)^j\\
> &\qquad-\sum_{j= 0}^{\min\left\{r,\left\lfloor \frac{m-k}{k}\right\rfloor\right\}}\binom{m-k-kj}{j}\binom{m-k-(k+1)j}{r-j}(-1)^j\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In order to determine the number $N(m,k,r)$  we consider words  with no consecutive equal characters at all.

These words are called Smirnov words or Carlitz words. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.)

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a binary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> **The number $N(m,k,r)$:**
>
> In order to set up for the binary strings we are looking for, we replace occurrences of $0$ in a Smirnov word by one up to $k-1$ zeros.  This  corresponds to a substitution of
>   \begin{align*}
> z&\longrightarrow z+z^2+\cdots+z^{k-1}=\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>    We replace occurrences of $1$ in a Smirnov word by any run of $1$'s with length $\geq 1$.
>   \begin{align*}
> z&\longrightarrow z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain a generating function $A(z,t)$ by substituting (3) and (4) in (2) and additionally marking each occurrence of one with $t$ in order to keep track of the Hamming-weight
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z,t)&=\left(1-\frac{\frac{zt}{1-zt}}{1+\frac{zt}{1-zt}}-\frac{\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z\left(1-z^{k-1}\right)}{1-z}}\right)^{-1}\\
> &=\frac{1-z^k}{1-(t+1)z+tz^{k+1}}\\
> \end{align*}

We denote with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series.

> We obtain using the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N(m,k,r)}&=[z^mt^r]A(z,t)\\
> &=[z^mt^r]\frac{1-z^k}{1-(t+1)z+tz^{k+1}}\\
> &\color{blue}{=[z^mt^r](1-z^k)\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j\left((t+1)-tz^k\right)^j}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

According to the factor $(1-z^k)$ in (5) we split the expression into two sums.

> We start with
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^mt^r]}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j\left((t+1)-tz^k\right)^j}\\
> &=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^m[z^{m-j}]\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}(-1)^lt^lz^{kl}(t+1)^{j-l}\tag{6}\\
> &=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^m[z^j]\sum_{l=0}^{m-j}\binom{m-j}{l}(-1)^lt^lz^{kl}(t+1)^{m-j-l}\tag{7}\\
> &=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor m/k\rfloor}[z^{kj}]\sum_{l=0}^{m-kj}\binom{m-kj}{l}(-1)^lt^lz^{kl}(t+1)^{m-kj-l}\tag{8}\\
> &=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor m/k\rfloor}\binom{m-kj}{j}(-1)^jt^j(t+1)^{m-(k+1)j}\tag{9}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\left\{r,\left\lfloor \frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor\right\}}\binom{m-kj}{j}(-1)^j[t^{r-j}](t+1)^{m-(k+1)j}\tag{10}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\left\{r,\left\lfloor \frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor\right\}}\binom{m-kj}{j}\binom{m-(k+1)j}{r-j}(-1)^j}\tag{11}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]G(z)=[z^p]z^{q}G(z)$. We also set the upper limit of the sum to $m$ since the exponent of $z^{m-j}$ is non-negative.
- In (7) we change the order of summation $j\rightarrow m-j$.
- In (8) we note the exponent of $z$ has to be a multiple of $k$ due to the factor $z^{kl}$ in the inner sum. We set $j\rightarrow kj$ accordingly.
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $z^{kj}$.
- In (10) we do a similar job with $[t^r]$ as we did with $[z^m]$ in (6).
- In (11) we select the coefficient of $t^{r-j}$.

> **Conclusion:** We observe the sum in (11) is the first sum stated at the right hand side of (1). According to the factor $(1-z^k)$ in (5) we obtain the second sum by replacing $m$ with $m-k$ and the claim follows.
>   $$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box$$

Finally we look at an example.

> **Example:** $N(m,k,r)$ with $m=7,k=3$ and $r=4$
>
> In accordance with OPs example string we calculate 
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{N(7,3,4)}&=\sum_{j}\binom{7-3j}{j}\binom{7-4j}{4-j}(-1)^j-\sum_{j}\binom{4-3j}{j}\binom{4-4j}{4-j}(-1)^j\\
> &=\left(\binom{7}{0}\binom{7}{4}-\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}\right)-\left(\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{4}-\binom{4}{1}\binom{0}{3}\right)\\
> &=(35-4)-(1-0)\\
> &\color{blue}{=30}
> \end{align*}
>
> The corresponding $30$ strings with length $7$, Hamming distance $4$ and no zero-runs of length $3$ are
>   \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0010111&0011011&0011101&0011110&0100111\\
>  0101011&0101101&0101110&0110011&0110101\\
>  0110110&0111001&0111010&0111100&1001011\\
>  1001101&1001110&1010011&1010101&1010110\\
>  1011001&1011010&1011100&1100101&1100110\\
>  1101001&1101010&1101100&1110010&1110100
>  \end{array}

---

*Note:* Here is some more detailed information to (6) due to OPs comment
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[z^mt^r]}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j\left((t+1)-tz^k\right)^j}\\
&=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^m[z^m]z^j\left((t+1)-tz^k\right)^j\\
&=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^m[z^m]z^j\left(-tz^k+(t+1)\right)^j\\
&=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^m[z^m]z^j\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}(-tz^k)^l(t+1)^{j-l}\\
&=[t^r]\sum_{j=0}^m[z^{m-j}]\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}(-1)^lt^lz^{kl}(t+1)^{j-l}\tag{6}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @N.Younger: Thanks! Good to see, the answer is useful! :-)

Comment: @N.Younger: You're welcome! It is correct, since $\frac{1}{1-a+b}=\frac{1}{1-(a-b)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a-b)^n$ whenever $|a-b|<1$.

Comment: @N.Younger: Did you already taken notice of the end of my updated answer?

Comment: Why do we know that $(-tz^k+(t+1))^j$ is equal to $\sum_{l=0}^j \binom{j}{l} (-tz^k)^l(t+1)^{j-1}$?

Comment: @N.Younger: Binomial theorem. . . . Maybe you should take a small rest? .. . :-)

Comment: @N.Younger: You're welcome! ... and $[z^{p-q}]G(z)=[z^p]z^qG(z)$. Think about $[z^2](2z+3z^2)=3$ and $[z^2](2z+3z^2)=[z^2](z(2+3z))=[z^{2-1}](2+3z)=[z](2+3z)=3$.

Comment: @N.Younger: Yeah! Nasty typo corrected! Thanks!

Comment: I almost understand it. ;-) A hopefully last question: How do I get $\lfloor \frac{m-k}{k} \rfloor$ in $(10)$? The remainder in $(10)$ is clear for me.

Comment: @N.Younger: Congrats to your staying power! :-) ... and thanks for indicating this second typo. As written in (1) the upper limit of the first sum is $\lfloor\frac{m}{k}\rfloor$. The second sum which respects multiplication with $z^{k}$ has upper limit $\lfloor\frac{m-k}{k}\rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I really want to understand the derivation and your typos are all corrected. :-D My very last question: How do you get $(11)$ by taking the coefficient $t^{r-j}$? Again with binomial theorem? ... I think I solved it. I used binomal theorem again, is this right?

Comment: @N.Younger: Correct: $[t^k](1+t)^n=\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience! Do you know some overviews for the coefficient extractor rules or so?

Comment: @N.Younger: A standard reference is *[this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9402216.pdf)* by D.E. Knuth. See also section 3.6 in Sprugnolis *[Introduction to Mathematical Methods in Combinatorics](http://www.dsi.unifi.it/~resp/Handbook.pdf)*.

Comment: In your example, the first binomial of the second sum should be $\binom{4-3j}{j}$ instead of $\binom{4-4j}{j}$. ;-)

Comment: @N.Younger: Thanks! Example corrected. The result $30$ is still valid. In fact I've checked it with a small code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same result. I had an mistake. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for $N(m,k,r)=$ number of binary strings with:
 *length $=m$, Hamming weight $=$ number of ones$=r$, and which
"do not contain $k$ consecutive zeros"*.

Taking the complement of the string (exchanging the zeros and ones), that is the same as:
*length $=m$, Hamming weight $=$ number of ones$=m-r$, and which
"do not contain $k$ consecutive ones"*.

[image: Consec_zeros_1]

Consider a binary string  with $s$ "$1$"'s and $q$ "$0$"'s in total. Let's put an additional (dummy) fixed $0$ at the start and at the end of the string.
We individuate as a *run* the consecutive $1$'s between two zeros, thereby including runs of null length. With this scheme we have a fixed number of $q+1$ runs.
If we sequentially enumerate the length of each run so individuated, we construct a bijection with the number of ways of putting
$s$ (undistinguishable) balls into $q+1$ (distinguishable) bins.
Now consider the case in which runs have a max length of $t$ ones, or that the bins have a limited capacity of $t$ balls, or otherwise the
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N_b (s,r,q + 1) = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm 0} \le {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \le r \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,q + 1}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.
 }$$
which as explained [in this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) is expressed as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N_b (s,t,q + 1)\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers  }s,q,t} \right.\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over t}\, \le \,q + 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \matrix{
  q + 1 \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  s + q - j\left( {t + 1} \right) \cr 
  s - j\left( {t + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)} 
 }$$
(which essentially is derived from the inclusion-exclusion principle).

Then, using your symbols, the number of strings with
 *length $=m$, Hamming weight $=$ number of ones$=r$, and which
" contain runs with* **max $k-1$** *consecutive zeros"*, equivalent to
*length $=m$, Hamming weight $=$ number of ones$=m-r$, and which
" contain runs with* **max $k-1$** *consecutive ones"*, is given by
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N(m,k,r)=N_b (m - r,k - 1,r + 1)
 }$$

And, as an example $N(7,3,4)=30$, as in the answer above.

Of course the number of strings with runs whatever is $N_b(m-r,m-r,r+1)={m \choose r}$.
So it is easy to compute also the number of strings with "(at least) one run of **exactly $k$** consecutive ones"
etc.

See also [this other related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045496/number-of-occurrences-of-k-consecutive-1s-in-a-binary-string-of-length-n-conta/2045737#2045737).