# Probability that tossing $10$ coins has $4$ consecutive heads

Tags: probability

I'd like to compute the probability of having a string of four consecutive heads after $10$ coin tosses.

I tried to solve this problem by considering $10$ blank spaces. To have $4$ consecutive heads, we can consider $7$ blank spaces, where the $7^{\text{th}}$ space is a string consisting of $4$ heads.

Then, there are $7!$ ways to arrange the $7$ spaces, and there are $4!$ internal permutations of the $4$ heads. Also, there are $2^{6}$ choices for the $6$ non-head coins.

This is all out of $10!$ arrangements and $2^{10}$ choices for the coins. So my probability is

$$\frac{7! \cdot 4! \cdot 2^6}{10! \cdot 2^{10}} = 0.00208333333,$$

which is wrong. I want to know what's wrong with my reasoning. I can't figure it out. I know there's a similar post, but I don't know what's wrong with my approach.

Comment: It is possible that the string contains $2$ blocks of $HHHH$, you double count such scenarios.  It is also possible that your string contains a block like $HHHHH$ , or longer, which greatly complicates this method.

Comment: My suggestion:  count recursively.  Any string, of length $≥5$,  without a block of $HHHH$ must end in one of $T,TH, THH, THHH$.

Comment: have a look at [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045496)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of possible outcomes is $2^{10}$

Using the counting method for the numerator .......

The number of outcomes with a single exact maximum $HHHH$ is

$HHHHT----- \Rightarrow 2^5 - 3$

$THHHHT----  \Rightarrow 2^4 - 1$

$-THHHHT---  \Rightarrow 2^4$

$--THHHHT--  \Rightarrow 2^4$

$---THHHHT-  \Rightarrow 2^4$

$----THHHHT  \Rightarrow 2^4 - 1$

$-----THHHH  \Rightarrow 2^5 - 3$

$$P(4H) = \frac{2(2)^5 + 5(2)^5 - 8}{2^{10}} = .132813$$

Where two $HHHH$ are allowed......

$$P(4H+) = \frac{2(2)^5 + 5(2)^5 - 2}{2^{10}} = .138672$$

The number of outcomes with at least one run of at least $4$ consecutive heads is $2^6 + 6(2)^5 - 5$

$HHHH------ \Rightarrow  2^6$

$THHHH----- \Rightarrow  2^5$

$-THHHH---- \Rightarrow  2^5$

$--THHHH--- \Rightarrow  2^5$

$---THHHH-- \Rightarrow  2^5$

$----THHHH- \Rightarrow  2^5 - 2$

$-----THHHH \Rightarrow 2^5 - 3$

$$P(\ge4H) = \frac{2^6+6(2)^5-5}{2^{10}} = .245117$$

Does anyone have a more formal/elegant method to check these answers?

Comment: could you explain the reason for subtracting? I understand it is due to overcounting but I can's see why you subtract exactly -3, -1 ecc ecc

Comment: The subtracting -3 and -1 are for the number of ways for a second HHHH  to occur when only considering a single HHHH. The other subtractions for the other 2 cases are for duplicate arrangements previously counted.