# Counting solutions to first order equation, with many integer variables

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, integers

I have seen many questions addressing the question to how many integer solutions exist to the following equation:
\begin{equation}
y_1 s+y_2+...+y_n=i,
\end{equation}
with each of the  $n$ variables $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ belonging to the $same$ set, being it infinite or finite. The problem in those case boils down to computing the coefficients of the related generating function, as in [this exhaustive question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800532/non-negative-solutions-with-upper-boundary-in-diophantine-equation?rq=1), which considers the diffrent cases of $y_i$ being $\ge 0$ or $y_i$ belonging to the finite set $[d,u]$, with $d<u$ integers.

I am curious to see what happens when the $n$ variables $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ belongs to $different$ sets. I propose the following.

Let's consider the following first order polynomial equation in $n$ variables $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, where each $x_i$ is within the finite set $\{0,1,...,F-1,F\}$ made by all integers between $0$ and $F$:
\begin{equation}
x_1 s+x_2s^2+...+x_ns^n=i,
\end{equation}
where $s$ and $i$ are whatever positive integers.

My goal is to get the number of solutions $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ to this polynomial equation, given $i$.

I remark that if $F=(s-1)$ I am simply looking at how many ways I can rewrite $i$ in a $s$-basis, hence there would be just 1 combination of $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ allowing that.

Comment: The integers from zero to $F$ don't form a field.

Comment: You are right, I correct immediately.

Comment: The easy case $s=1$ should be explored first.  When $s \gt 1$ the powers $s^\ell$ will of course grow rapidly.  I'm not sure why you target the sum to be $i$ when the term $F+1$ is known already to push the sum to at least that.

Comment: I polished that, thank you!