# How many necklaces made of black and white beads (k total, x black) have at least y consecutive black beads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

Consider all necklaces consisting of black and white beads, of length k, containing x black beads.

How many such necklaces contain y consecutive black beads somewhere in the necklace? (y is less than or equal to x.)

This post considers the question for strings rather than necklaces:
[Number of binary strings containing at least n consecutive 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780969/number-of-binary-strings-containing-at-least-n-consecutive-1)

(It's possible to make this question harder by considering only aperiodic necklaces, but the simpler question above is fine.)

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of the strings question? white = 0, black = 1.

Comment: @kevinkayaks  Necklaces are a little different from strings.  For example, there are 5 binary strings with four 0s and one 1, but there is only one necklace.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the cycle index of the cyclic group

$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$

Supposing that we  have $n = b+w$  beads with $b$ black  and $w$ white
and there is a run of black  beads of length at least $q$ (maximum run
length at  least $q$) we  get from  the Polya Enumeration  Theorem the
closed form

$$Q_{b,w} = [B^b W^w] Z(C_n; B+W)
- [B^b W^w] \sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
Z\left(C_m; \sum_{p=1}^{q-1} B^p \sum_{p=1}^w W^p\right).$$

Here we have the boundary case that $Q_{0,w}$ is one if $q=0$ and zero
otherwise and that $Q_{b,0}$ is one if $b\ge q$ and zero otherwise.
Note that by doing the substitution we find

$$[B^b W^w] Z(C_n; B+W)
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|(b,w)}
\varphi(d) {n/d\choose b/d}.$$

When we ask about binary necklaces on $n$ beads with maximum run length
for black beads being at least $q$ we find the quantity

$$P_n = \sum_{k=0}^n Q_{k, n-k}.$$

These formulas  have an  implicit extra parameter  $q.$ We  present an
implementation in Maple that also includes an enumeration routine that
was  used to  verify these  statistics.  We can  compute some  example
sequences. Here  is the count  for necklaces  with the same  number of
black and white beads with the maximum run length at least zero (admit
all, this is $Q_{b,b,0}$):

$$1, 2, 4, 10, 26, 80, 246, 810, 2704, \ldots$$

which points us to [OEIS A003239](https://oeis.org/A003239) where these
data are confirmed. As an additional sanity check we can compute the
count of all binary necklaces (admit all, which is $P_{n,0}$):

$$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 14, 20, 36, 60, 108, 188, 352, 632, 
\\ 1182, 2192, 4116, 7712, \ldots$$

which   points   to   [OEIS   A000031](https://oeis.org/A000031)   for
confirmation.  We  obtain one  minus  this  sequence when  we  compute
$P_{n,1}$ which  is correct  as well (omit  only the  white monochrome
necklace).  The sequence  with maximum  run length  at least  three is
given by

$$0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 60, 113, 220, 419, 813, 
\\ 1565, 3033, 5855, \ldots$$

Maximum run length at least four is

$$0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 63, 124, 241, 475, 
\\ 930, 1831, 3593, \ldots$$

To conclude  we present  the sequence  where we  have four  more black
beads than white ones and the maximum run length for black is at least
four (this is $Q_{w+4,w,4}$):

$$1, 3, 10, 34, 116, 411, 1464, 5292, 19246, 
\\ 70533, 259766, 961423, \ldots$$

We have  posted these values here  to encourage the reader  to present
their  own implementation  and verify  them, or  perhaps simplify  the
formula  from the  introduction. The  Maple code  was as  follows (PET
first, followed by ENUM):

```
with(numtheory);
with(combinat);

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res, k;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local d;

    1/n*add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n));
end;

pet_neckl_simple :=
proc(b,w)
local n, d;

    n := b+w;
    1/n*add(phi(d)*binomial(n/d, b/d),
                d in divisors(gcd(b,w)));
end;

Q :=
proc(b,w,q)
option remember;
local res, rep, p, m;
    if b=0 then
        if q=0 then return 1 else return 0 fi;
    fi;

    if w=0 then
        if b >= q then return 1 else return 0 fi;
    fi;

    rep := add(B^p, p=1..q-1)*add(W^p, p=1..w);

    for m to floor((b+w)/2) do
        res := res
        + pet_varinto_cind(rep, pet_cycleind_cyclic(m));
    od;

    pet_neckl_simple(b, w)
    - coeff(coeff(expand(res), B, b), W, w);
end;

P :=
proc(n,q)
option remember;
local k;

    add(Q(k,n-k,q), k=0..n);
end;

QX :=
proc(b,w,q)
option remember;
local n, wpos, idx, maxrun, len,
    rot, orbit, orbits, src;

    if b=0 then
        if q=0 then return 1 else return 0 fi;
    fi;

    if w=0 then
        if b >= q then return 1 else return 0 fi;
    fi;

    n := b+w; orbits := table();

    for wpos in choose(b+w,w) do
        maxrun := 0;

        for idx from 2 to w do
            len := wpos[idx] - wpos[idx-1] - 1;
            if len > maxrun then
                maxrun := len;
            fi;
        od;

        len := wpos[1]+n - wpos[w] - 1;
        if len > maxrun then
            maxrun := len;
        fi;

        if maxrun >= q then
            orbit := [];

            src :=
            table([seq(`B`, idx=1..n)]);

            for idx to w do
                src[wpos[idx]] := `W`;
            od;

            for rot from 0 to n-1 do
                orbit :=
                [op(orbit),
                 [seq(src[1+((idx+rot) mod n)],
                      idx = 0..n-1)]];
            od;

            orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
        fi;
    od;

    numelems(orbits);
end;

PX :=
proc(n,q)
option remember;
local k;

    add(QX(k,n-k,q), k=0..n);
end;
```